# c++ use list in a class(.cpp .h)

Tags: c++, class

can somebody tell me why doesn't this runs?
Can u tell me a solution

main.cpp

```
#include "test"
#include <list>
int main(){
list<int> variables; // <- runs
return 0;
}
```

Test.h

```
#include<list>
class test{
list<int> elems; // <-error here "list was not declared"
void method(){
}
}
```

Test.h

```
#include "Test.h"
void Test:method(){
// some code
}
```

the compiler say that list wasnot declared,
but if i put list in main it runs perfecly.
i already try this in several compilers.

can someone tell me why doesn't this runs?

thanks in advance :D

Comment: Both cases should fail, as you forgot `std::`. before `list`.

Answer (score 0):

if "test" is a library you should do

```
#include "test.h"
```

that is because it is different than libraries such as  or  since you made it.

Also, they should fail, since you don't have std::. before list